# Completing a unitary matrix given a column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-completion

I am given a unit vector $e=1/\sqrt{n}(1,1,\ldots,1)'$ and the problem is to construct an $n \times n$ (real) unitary matrix $U$ which will contain $e$ as the last column. I understand that there are infinitely many such $U$ ($n>2$). I wonder if there is a very simple closed form for $U$, i.e., very simple $n-1$ vectors orthogonal to each other and to $e$.

Comment: What you call a real unitary matrix is more usually referred to as an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Have you seen Hadamard matrices?

Comment: @joriki, yes its surely "orthogonal". J.M. I have seen a only few of them :)

Comment: also, you can always extend the given vector to a basis for $R^n$ and then use the gram schmidt process to get what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns of $$\pmatrix{1&1&1&1&1\cr1&-1&1&1&1\cr1&0&-2&1&1\cr1&0&0&-3&1\cr1&0&0&0&-4\cr}$$ are pairwise orthogonal. If you divide the 1st column by $\sqrt5$, the second by $\sqrt2$, the third by $\sqrt 6$, the fourth by $\sqrt12$, and the fifth by $\sqrt20$, you should get an orthogonal matrix. Then you just have to move the first column to the far right.

This is the case $n=5$, but the pattern should be clear.

Comment: Wow! Great! I was looking for exactly something like that. Thank you very much. Does this type of matrix has a special name?

Comment: Not that I know of, but, then again, not every matrix is a personal friend of mine.

Comment: @Tapu: [Yes.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2312989)

Comment: @Tapu: [MATLAB has them built-in](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gallery.html#f84-1000083): `gallery('orthog',n,4)`; for *Mathematica*, you can use `Helmert[n_] := DiagonalMatrix[1/Sqrt[Prepend[Table[j (j + 1), {j, n - 1}], n]]].SparseArray[{{1, j_} -> 1, {i_, j_} /; i > j -> 1, Band[{2, 2}] -> -Range[n - 1]}, {n, n}]`

Comment: @J.M. The reference is great (I know the author is a great matrician:)). Thank you.