# Create a unitary matrix out of a column vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I need an algorithmic way, to create a unitary matrix out of a first, given, column vector. i.e. if the column vector was $(0 1 1 1)^T$, I'd need an algorithm to complete it to a matrix like this.
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The content of the other column vectors is not relevant, as long as it makes the matrix unitary. The only partial answer I found was in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89075/completing-a-unitary-matrix-given-a-column) previous post, but it only covers vectors containing only $1$.

Does anyone know a smart way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Based on the answer by @ben-grossmann, I've written this Python function to create the matrix, if anyone else needs it.

```
def create_unitary(v):
    dim = v.size
    # Return identity if v is a multiple of e1
    if v[0][0] and not np.any(v[0][1:]):
        return np.identity(dim)
    e1 = np.zeros(dim)
    e1[0] = 1
    w = v/np.linalg.norm(v) - e1
    return np.identity(dim) - 2*((np.dot(w.T, w))/(np.dot(w, w.T)))
```

Comment: If $Q\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ such that $Q^{\intercal}Q=I$ then its more appropriate to rather call it an orthogonal matrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution that I find elegant is to use the [Householder matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) with the correct first column. One way to build this matrix is as follows.

Let $v$ denote the desired first column. Let $e_1$ denote the column-vector $e_1 = (1\ \ 0\ \ \cdots \ \ 0)^T$. First of all, if $v$ is a multiple of $e_1$, then it suffices to either use $I$ or $-I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. If not, then let $w$ denote the vector $w = v/\|v\| - e_1$. The Householder matrix corresponding to the reflection across the hyperplane orthogonal to $w$ is given by
$$
H = I - 2 \frac{ww^T}{w^Tw}.
$$
Applying the process to $v = (0,1,1,1)^T$ leads to the matrix
$$
H = \left[\begin{matrix}
0 & \frac 13 \sqrt{3} & \frac 13 \sqrt{3} & \frac 13 \sqrt{3}\\
\frac 13 \sqrt{3} & \frac 23 & -\frac 13 & -\frac 13\\
\frac 13 \sqrt{3} & -\frac 13 & \frac 23 & -\frac 13\\
\frac 13\sqrt{3} & -\frac 13 & -\frac 13 & \frac 23\end{matrix}\right].
$$

---

Another approach that bears mentioning: we could do the following using the [`null_space`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html) method.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

def create_unitary(v):
    return np.hstack((v,la.null_space(v.T)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I looked for!

Comment: @Robinbux No problem. Regarding you're code: keep in mind that you will get a division by zero error whenever $v$ is a multiple of $e_1$. For this reason, I address this case separately in my answer.

Comment: good catch, thank you. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to start by extending the given column to any invertible square matrix $A$ (for example by adding standard basis vectors). You can then apply the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to the columns of $A$ to obtain an orthogonal (unitary) matrix $U$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the vector of interest $(v)$, choose another arbitrary vector $(a)$. Use this vector pair to create an skew-hermitian matrix $(S)$, then use a [Cayley Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Matrix_map) to generate the desired unitary matrix $(U)$
$$\eqalign{
S &= av^\dagger - va^\dagger \\
U &= (I+S)^{-1}(I-S)\\
}$$
The Householder transform suggested in the other answers is also a good idea.

### Update

Re-reading the question, the goal was to have $v$ appear as the first column of $U$.

To accomplish that, the Householder transform is the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line command that generates a list of 1d arrays of unitary column vectors, then stacks them into one 2d array using np.stack.

for any matrix x,

```
import numpy as np  
import scipy.linalg as la

x_unit= np.stack( [x[:,i]/la.norm(x[:,i]) for i in range(x.shape[0])], axis=1)
```

you can make this a lambda function and call it whenever you want. then call an array, lets say B, of any dimension,

```
unit= lambda x: np.stack( [x[:,i]/la.norm(x[:,i]) for i in range(x.shape[0])], axis=1)
     
unit(B)
```